# How do I show cents when I am writing a code to count total money, the code below is only showing a whole number (such as $1)

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a code in C# that prints out the total of dollars and cents I have. I have the first part done, but the end of the code won't show how much cents there is when I run the whole code, it only shows a whole number (such as $1), when I need the code to show something like $1.56. What am I missing in the program in order to show this?

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of quarters: ");
int quarters = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of dimes: ");
int dimes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of nickels: ");
int nickels = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter number of pennies: ");
int pennies = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

double dollars = (int)(((quarters * 0.25) + (dimes * 0.10) + (nickels * 0.05) + (pennies * 0.01)) % 1 * 100);

Console.WriteLine("Your total is $" + dollars);
```

When I typed in 4 quarters, 0 dimes, 0 nickels, and 1 penny, it shows the result as $1 not $1.01

Comment: Why do you mod by 100?

Comment: why do you `double dollars = (int) ... stuff` ? dont  `(int)` it

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing the result as `int`, so the decimals are cut

```
double dollars = (int)(((quarters * 0.25) + (dimes * 0.10) + (nickels * 0.05) + (pennies * 0.01)) % 1 * 100);
```

Do not force to `int`, on the contrary, force to double

```
double dollars = ((quarters * 0.25) + (dimes * 0.10) + (nickels * 0.05) + (pennies * 0.01)) % 1 * 100;
```

But, since you are handling money, I would recommend to handle everything with [`decimal`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/decimal-vs-double-difference?forum=csharpgeneral)

```
decimal dollars = ((quarters * 0.25) + (dimes * 0.10) + (nickels * 0.05) + (pennies * 0.01)) % 1 * 100;
```

Better explained in [dotnet perls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/decimal)

> Decimal accurately stores numeric data. The .NET Framework offers this
>   type for programs where rounding errors are harmful. Decimal stores
>   large and small numbers with many digits after the decimal place.

## EDIT

> When I put in decimal dollars instead of double dollars, I then get
>   the error, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

It is becuse you need all the operation of the same type, you can do

```
    int quarters =1;
    int dimes = 1;
    int nickels = 1;
    int pennies = 1;

    decimal dollars = ((quarters * 0.25m) + (dimes * 0.10m) + (nickels * 0.05m) + (pennies * 0.01m)) % 1 * 100;

    Console.WriteLine("Your total is $" + dollars);
```

Note the use of a `m` after the number, this is to tell the compiler that the type is decimal or Money, not double.

Comment: When I put in decimal dollars instead of double dollars, I then get the error, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (CS0266)"